# error al insert de mysqli en php

Tags: php, mysqli

¿como puedo hacer esto en Php me sale error de encasulado?

```
<?php 
mysqli_query($conexion, 'SELECT \'DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),''%y-%m-%d'').\'');
?>
```

me sale este error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in C:\xampp\htdocs\Panel Administracion V3\Panel Administracion V4\Panel
>   Administracion V5\registro.php on line 2

Comment: Le sobran caracteres a tu consulta y debes  combinar de forma inteligente el uso de las comillas dobles y las simples en este caso, prueba así: **`mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%y-%m-%d') fecha");`**, he dado el alias `fecha` a la columna que resultará de la consulta. Y... eso no es un `INSERT`... no entiendo a qué viene el título de tu pregunta. Y otra cosa, ¿siendo que desde PHP puedes obtener la fecha actual, ¿por qué molestar a la base de datos para eso?

Comment: puse un comentario simple sin include obvio no es para un select si no para un insert el caso seria el mismo error

Comment: lapregunta seria para ti por que no respondistes? para calificar?

Answer (score 0):

Le sobran caracteres a tu consulta y debes combinar de forma inteligente el uso de las comillas dobles y las simples en este caso.

Prueba así:

```
mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%y-%m-%d') fecha");
```

He dado el alias `fecha` a la columna que resultará de la consulta.

> **RECOMENDACIÓN:**
>
> Siendo que desde PHP puedes obtener la fecha actual, en un escenario
>   real no vale la pena *molestar* a la base de datos para esto.
>   Consumirá más recursos, porque tienes que conectarte para sacar la
>   fecha actual, etc.
>
> En el entorno de PHP bastaría con `date("y-m-d")`,  por ejemplo:
>
> ```
> $hoy=date("y-m-d");  
> echo $hoy;
> ```
>
> O para cosas más avanzadas puedes crear un objeto `DateTime` haciendo algo así: `$hoy=new DateTime();`